# iframe onload with src not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, onload, src

I have a `JavaScript` program that gets the last modified date of a txt file. The code works fine in Firefox but for some reason, it does nothing in IE11. My code is listed below.

`JavaScript` code:

```
function getLastMod(){
    var myFrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    var lastMod = new Date(myFrm.contentWindow.document.lastModified);
    var getSpan = document.getElementById('LastModified');
    getSpan.innerHTML += "<font color=red> (File Last Updated: " + lastMod.toLocaleString() + ")</font>";
}
```

`HTML` code:

```
<span id="LastModified"></span>
<iframe id="myIframe" onload="getLastMod()" src="date.txt" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you getting a console error?  Is `myFrm` defined?

Comment: Im not getting a console error and yes, `myFrm` is the first variable declared in the function.

Comment: More specifically, I meant is it getting populated?  Or is it null?  Can you log it out?

Comment: Yes it is getting populated. As stated above, the script works fine in Firefox but just not in IE11.

Comment: Try getting rid of your `font` tag.  That's been deprecated for a while.  IE11 may not support it.

Comment: Also, the proper way to put that tag in there is to use `appendChild`, not `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I tried to define the event in the tag.  I had better results assigning the event from within javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myIframe').onload = function() {
        getLastMod();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this already and, once again, everything works fine with Firefox but not with IE11

Comment: Scratch what I said, I used this in my HTML and got it working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help :)